# Clarification on Identifying Columns with All Zeros in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question regarding filtering data in R, specifically when using the colSums function to identify columns with all zeros.I am working with a dataframe df, and I observed that when I use the expression `colSums(df[, -1]) == 0`, it correctly identifies some columns with all zeros but fails to recognize column 'A' as having all zeros.

Here is the code snippet for reference:

```
#data
df <- data.frame(
  SP = c("MCCB", "ABC", "DEF"),
  A = c(2, 0, 0),
  B = c(0, 3, 3),
  C = c(2, 4, 1),
  D = c(4, 0, 0),
  E = c(0, 0, 0),
  F = c(0, 1, 2)
)

View(df)
# Identify columns with all zeros
zero_sum_cols <- colSums(df[,-1]) == 0

print(zero_sum_cols)
```

I got this below

```
A     B     C     D     E     F 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

My doubt is why resulting logical vector indicates that column 'A' has zero values (FALSE), even though it contains non-zero (2).
I was trying to filter the data in order to get non-zero value from first column. However, the current approach using `df[, zero_sum_cols, drop = FALSE]` doesn't yield the expected result.

```
result <- df[, zero_sum_cols, drop = FALSE]
# Print the result
print(result)
D
1 4
2 0
3 0
```

Any insights or corrections would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Column `A` contains zeros, but not every value it contains is `0`.  In other words, it is not "all zeroes".  Your output seems to be as expected to me.

Comment: `colSums(df[,-1])` is not the best function, it can return `0` if you have pos and neg values. A better call is something like `colSums(abs(df[,-1]) > 0) == 0`.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the results? The 'A' result of `FALSE` indicates that there is at least one non-zero number in the `A` column, not *"column 'A' has zero values"*.

Comment: colSums(df[-1,-1]) == 0
    A     B     C     D     E     F 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I got, I did messup with row and column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly identify zero columns, you want `colSums` with zeros equal to `nrow`. Setting `colSums` to zero is prone to cancel out to zero. You coul also use `all` or `matrixStats::colAlls`, which might be more effective.

```
> df1
  X1 X2 X3
1 -1  0  0
2  1  0  1
3 -1  0  2
4  1  0  3
> colSums(df1) == 0  ## wrong
   X1    X2    X3 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
> colSums(df1 == 0) == nrow(df1)  ## correct
   X1    X2    X3 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE 
> matrixStats::colAlls(df1 == 0)  ## correct
   X1    X2    X3 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

To subset you can do

```
> df1[, colSums(df1 == 0) != nrow(df1), drop=FALSE]
  X1 X3
1 -1  0
2  1  1
3 -1  2
4  1  3
> df1[, !matrixStats::colAlls(df1 == 0), drop=FALSE]
  X1 X3
1 -1  0
2  1  1
3 -1  2
4  1  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(-1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3), 4))
```

Comment: thank you for answer, != nrow(df1) was the crucial paertThe matrix approach was also helpful

Comment: @Umar It can be confusing, I know, but I'm glad you understood :)